# #include<thread>, error could not open source file "thread"

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

i'm looking forward to implement multi-threads in c++ on windows,i found link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/ that as explanation on threads,in given example they have mentioned header naming from thread,actually i'm writing code in Microsoft visual studio 2010,which says the error could not open source file "thread",please help me whether this can help,or please suggest me any other site that help , actually i'm beginner for advanced c++,thanks in advance.

Comment: If memory serves, VC++ didn't add `<thread>` until version 2012 (or maybe 2013; it's definitely present in VS 2013).

Comment: If you can't update to a recent enough standard library, [Boost's thread library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread.html) is very similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<thread>` is a C++11 header, and Visual Studio 2010 does not implement C++11. Try updating to Visual Studio 2012 or 2013.

Comment: @congusbonbus ,but you can add external libraries for visual studio 2010,right??,correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Santhosh yes, but `<thread>` is part of the C++11 standard library, which is generally provided by the compiler, in this case Visual Studio. If you want to use third party libraries you'd go with a solution like Mike Seymour suggested, i.e. use Boost.

Answer (score -1):

Try using AfxBeginThread.  It does work in VS 2010.

Comment: `AfxBeginThread` is part of MFC. Since nothing in the question indicates, that this is for MFC, this is not an answer to the question. The Windows API exports [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx), and the CRT offers [_beginthread/_beginthreadex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx). Both of these can be used in any C++ application on Windows.